# WCF Message Security implementation with custom attributes

Tags: .net, wcf, security, message

How can i implement message security in WCF with custom attributes,

One way of doing this by UserNamePasswordValidator which accepts user name and password 
but in my case I have to pass 2 more attribute that is company and region to authenticate the user.

Please suggest the solution for achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop re-inventing the wheel! This has already been done - see:

[Foundations: Declarative WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163382.aspx)

Excellent article, comes with full source code for you to use and adapt (if needed).

Comment: Thanks,Article is useful and I achieved this by using UsernamePassword security with some tweaks.